# Remove malformed part from img tag in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, draftjs, html-rendering, react-draft-wysiwyg

I am using react-draft-wysiwyg editor in a ReactJS project where I need to render the editor content as React DOM html element on a next page.

All the contents written in the editor get rendered properly with formatting except and image.

If I attach any image url in the editor then the url appears as anchor tag as the src attribute of the img tag.

I need to remove that unwanted malformed anchor tag from the image src attribute and replace it will the image url

Here is sample html

```
<p dir="auto"><p><strong>Hello test uyyuuyuiiyc </strong></p><br />
<p><br></p><br />
<p><br></p><br />
<figure>

 <img src="<a href="https://www.stepuplearning.net/logo/logo.png" 
 rel="nofollow">https://www.stepuplearning.net/logo/logo.png</a>" height="auto" width="auto"/> 


</figure><br />
<p><br></p></p>
```

Please help me to fix this out. Much thanks.

Comment: can you create a working example of your problem in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) or [jsfiddle](jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @Morta1, it is about parse out those unwanted part and replace it with link using react javascript.